# Nested route not rendering and removing previous UI with exact prop

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm having a problem with nesting routes with react-router-dom. I've modified the example they provide in the docs [in this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-playground-r37zb?file=/src/App.js).

As you can see, I'm trying to get to `/topics/:topicId` but it displays `404 Not Found`. The original example provided in the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting) has this code:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/">
    <Home />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/topics">
    <Topics />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

However, in my fork I added the `exact` prop to the `/topics` route because I need to remove the `<Topics />` UI and just render the `<Topic />` UIs. I've stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57590904/react-router-v5-nested-routes-not-found) regarding the use of the `exact` prop on the `Route`. But, like I said previously, I need the contents of `<Topics />` removed and only `<Topic />` to render, and without the `exact` prop it will render both of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Route to render `Topic` :

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a separate route for `/topics/:topicId`.

```js
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/">
    <Home />
  </Route>

  <Route path="/topics/: topicId">
    <Topic />
  </Route>

  <Route path="/topics">
    <Topics />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

Comment: did you check the sandbox? The route for the `<Topic />` is placed in the `<Topics />` component, like the one in react router docs. However, without the exact prop, both `<Topics />` and `<Topic />` components render on the same page. I need to have so that `<Topics />` is removed and then `<Topic />` is rendered.

Comment: Your sandbox is broken and If you are using nested routes, then parent route (in your case `/topics`) will always be rendered. and if you used exact on `/topics` then `/topics/:topicId` won't match, hence 404.